# What is the ruling on Memes ? Is it halal or haram

Tags: halal-haram, doubts

Is there any verse or hadeed that indicates the making Memes
is sin.

**Meme** definition :an image, video, piece of text, etc., typically humorous in nature, that is copied and spread rapidly by internet users, often with slight variations.

Example :https://images.app.goo.gl/AdDjUiUEB57JBL3W7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assalamu alaikum brother,
As we can see memes are images. Whatever you call them , they are all images at the end of the day. And regarding images prophet Mohammed s.w.a.w has said that " at the day of judgement those who are photogenic will be dragged into hell directly"
So don't be fooled by shaitan's Fancy word trick . Stay away from images , photos ( unless the photos are obligated i.e. in voter ID , driving license etc)

Answer (score 0):

Jokes and puns are not considered haram in any way so why should memes? Memes are not haram in any way unless the meme Contains sex jokes or is offensive. If you are just reading a random funny meme you won't go to hell for doing it. Islam is about living a healthy life while staying close to Allah. That's my opinion

Answer (score -2):

i think that nowadays weather you want try or not you cant stay away from movies music and pictures, some bring a verse saying that "at the day of judgement those who are photogenic will be dragged into hell directly"
And that is something we barley are able to do so let me tell you this, if a Muslim has iman does good deeds and prays 5 times a day pictures won't drag him to hell. Don't be hard on yourself memes are jokes things to laugh at if not inappropriate. This is what i believe may god bless us all